# Java Script Image Slide Show (Annimate function)

Tags: javascript

I have a problem understanding javascript code.These are my first steps in javascript and I'm trying to make a Javascript slide show. Please explain me how

```
var timePassed = new Date - start; **and**
var progress = timePassed / opts.duration;
```

works in this function:-

```
<script>
function animate(opts){
var start = new Date;
var id = setInterval(function(){
    var timePassed = new Date - start;
    var progress = timePassed / opts.duration;
    if (progress > 1){
        progress = 1;
    }
    var delta = opts.delta(progress);
    opts.step(delta);
    if (progress == 1){
        clearInterval(id);
        opts.callback();
    }
}, opts.delay || 17);

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timePassed` is how much time passed since the beginning of the animation (current date - start date).

`progress` is the ratio of how much time passed over the total duration of the animation. This value will be between 0 and 1 (1 means the animation is over).

For exemple, if `opts.duration` is 1000ms, after 500ms elapsed, progress will be `500 / 1000 = 0.5` (= 50% of the total duration of the animation). When `progress` is 1 (1000 / 1000), the animation is done and the callback is called.